# Writing to file outside var/www

Tags: php, html, raspbian

How would one go through with writing to a file outside the var/www/ directory?

I am trying to write to "/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness", a file controlling the brightness of the onboard LED on the Raspberry Pi, but I assume it would be the same for all files outside var/www/.

I have set the permissions so that anyone can read/write by using

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /sys/class/leds/led0
```

This is my HTML/php code:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['button1'])) {
        toggle();
    }
    function toggle()
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $f = fopen("/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness", "r");
        $value = fgets($f);

        fclose($f);

        if ($value = "1") {
            $value = "0";
        } elseif ($value = "0") {
            $value = "1";
        }
        $f = fopen("/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness", "w+");

        fwrite($f, $value);

        fclose($f);
    }
?>

<html><body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <input type=button onClick='location.href="?button1"' value='Toggle Lamp'>
</body></html>
```

There is no response whatsoever. No errors, no output in the file, no nothing.

P.S. Please note that it is supposed to be `/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness`
and not `/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness.txt`

It is a plain file, not a txt.

I apologize if this is 100% backwards, I'm new to HTML and web programming in general :)

Comment: What error do you get? (Please note that you first open `brightness` for reading - then write to `brightness.txt` - it is **not** the same file)

Comment: what value are you looking to get?

Comment: EDIT: IGNORE. I will try once again with the error pointed out by h2ooooooo fixed

Comment: You run the code and if there's an error you'll either get it in your PHP/webserver error log (and an error 500) or you'll see it on the page itself. You can force errors on by using `error_reporting(E_ALL)` as the first thing in your code.

Comment: $f = fopen("/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness", "r"); needs to be $f = fopen("/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness.txt", "r"); . You can open the txt file and check what value you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have much memory on the rasp, I assume you are using it with nginx+php-fpm rather than with slow and heavy Apache. With php-fpm you can run a PHP script by its owner easily, so you'd simply change the script owner to root, make sure the script works (security!) and then you can write whatever file you want.

```
chown root:www-data <script that writes to sys file>

<?php
exec('echo ' . intval($value) . ' > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness');
```

Comment: I am running apache, is there a way to do that with apache?

Comment: php-fpm / fastcgi / fcgi / suexec is also available for apache. But nginx is really better, easier to configure, 3 times faster, less resources..